# Calculation of mathematical text in textbox

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is there a function to calculate the mathematical text in the text box in VBA? For example, can we calculate the expression 1+2 entered in the text box?
I have used the calculate option in Word using VBA to calculate the selected text (`Selection.Calculate`), but it gives an error in Excel.

Comment: [**Application.Evaluate method**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a function to calculate the mathematical text in a text box?

Yes. Example:

```
TextBox1.Value = Application.Evaluate("1+2")
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [Calculate math operation in textbox. [VBA] [EXCEL] - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46628330/calculate-math-operation-in-textbox-vba-excel)
- [Simple math using Text box values in a userform | MrExcel Message Board](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/simple-math-using-text-box-values-in-a-userform.326943/)